# Industrial IO board ST X-NUCLEO-PLC01A1 - design features

Tags: plc, io, industrial

For a project I want to buy an [X-NUCLEO-PLC01A1](https://www.st.com/en/ecosystems/x-nucleo-plc01a1.html).

So I studied the [schematic](https://www.st.com/resource/en/schematic_pack/x-nucleo-plc01a1_schematic.pdf) and datasheets ([CLT01-38SQ7](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/clt01-38sq7.pdf))([VNI8200XP](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/vni8200xp.pdf)), but there are still some points that confuse me.

1. What is the purpose of D20 - is it a reverse polarity protection? If so, why is it in the GND path?

[image]

2. Why is the supply voltage of CLT01 (VC) connected to 24V through a 2k2 resistor?

[image]
[image]

3. What's the function of the "surge test" area with the 2 x 4n7F capacitors? Are the capacitors implemented to the PCB, because it looks like they have no footprint.
   [image]
   [image]
   [image]
4. Suppose I want to use this in an industrial commercial product. Would these IO be of the same ruggedness as in a commercial PLC? If not, what would be missing?

Answer (score 0):

1. PGND and GND are not the same, maybe you find the answer in some app note.

[image]
[image]

2. The CLT01 is not supplied there (SPM), it's just a jumper for selecting different mode of SPI register length.

[image]

3. They have a footprint, it's in your photo. You can solder them and perform the test.
4. I do think so, this is the goal of this IC.

Comment: regarding 1. I somehow missed this in the datasheet. Clear now.
regarding 2. Is still not clear to me. In the picture I attach above I dont mean the Jumper. South-east of the jumper VC of CLT01 is connected to VC west of the jumper. This VC is fed by 24V through a 2k2 resistor. Or am I missing something?